# Property 'Attachments' is 'ReadOnly' in visual studio

Tags: .net, attachment

Hello i was recoding one of my programs when the error Property 'Attachments' is 'ReadOnly' came is this piece of coding.

```
MyMailMessage.Attachments = "\WebPassFind.txt"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what framework/language?

Comment: Visual studio, windows application.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: Framework is .NET as the tag shows. Language my guess is VB as the line doesn't end with semi-colon

Comment: Vb .net is the language

Comment: Sorry I'm not that good at programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be working with [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or with [System.Web.Mail.MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.attachments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The `Attachments` property on either one is read-only: one is an `AttachmentCollection`,  the other is an `IList(Of MailAttachment)`.

Rather than trying to set the property to a `String`, you should use the `Add` method of the property to add whichever type of attachment object is expected.

Comment: Could you please put it in coding, because I'm not really that great at this 

Comment: You haven't provided the type of the `MyMailMessage` variable, so I don't know what type you're working with.